# Modem only allows outgoing traffic from specific IP, how should I configure the switch behind it?

Tags: switch, router, dhcp

I've got a satellite modem with an 8 port switch behind it.  The modem has an IP of 192.168.128.100 and only allows traffic from 192.168.128.200.

So I connected the modem to my WAN port, set up my switch IP as 192.168.128.200 and the gateway as 192.168.128.100.  Devices on the switch use DHCP with the IP address set per MAC address, in the 192.168.128.201-209 range. **Unfortunately none of those devices are able to ping outside past the modem. Does the modem see all traffic as 192.168.128.200 or does it see it as the addresses behind the switch?**

For reference, the hardware is a Hughes 9502 BGAN Satellite modem, the switch is a DLink DSR-150.

Comment: Questions about home networking, consumer-grade devices, and ISP end-users are all specifically off topic. You can ask this question on [su].

Answer (score 1):

> The modem has an IP of 192.168.128.100 and only allows traffic from
>   192.168.128.200

If this is an absolute requirement which cannot be changed because of limitations on the ISP's side, your only option would be to install a router between the modem and a switch. Once you have done that, you can configure the router to NAT all user traffic which is destined for non-local networks.

In other words, your internal network would receive IP addresses from one range (e.g 192.168.0.0/24), but once they send their traffic through the router, their source IP addresses will be changed to 192.168.128.200. This results in the modem allowing the traffic through. When the return traffic comes in the modem will pass the traffic to the router and the router will "un-NAT" it and pass it to the host who originally requested the traffic.